# Unable to find a specification for `RNPermissions` depended upon by `Permission-LocationAlways` in React Native iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, cocoapods

In React Native project while installing pod in iOS

```
$cd ios
$pod install
```

below error shown

```
Adding a custom script phase for Pod RNFBApp: [RNFB] Core Configuration
Adding a custom script phase for Pod RNFBCrashlytics: [RNFB] Crashlytics Configuration
Auto-linking React Native modules for target amway: RNFBApp, RNFBCrashlytics, and RNGoogleSignin
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
!Unable to find a specification for `RNPermissions` depended upon by `Permission-LocationAlways`

You have either:

-mistyped the name or version.
-not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

But in other system pod install is working fine with no issues.

steps followed:

```
-npm install (node-modules get updated based on package.json)
-cd ios
-pod install
```

then it show above error but in other system these steps works fine with no error.

Also when I take a zip from other system, that run properly but when I try to modify anything or update pod it breaks with those error.

Both system have same MacOS, Xcode, cocoapods and node version. But don't know what diff or my system have.

Below is react-native info:

```
System:
OS: macOS 13.2.1
CPU: (8) x64 Apple M1
Memory: 7.39 MB / 8.00 GB
Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 14.17.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: Not Found
npm: 6.14.13 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 2023.03.13.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.12.0 - /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: DriverKit 22.2, iOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: 2021.3 AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335
Xcode: 14.2/14C18 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: 11.0.17 - /usr/bin/javac
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 16.13.1
react-native: 0.63.2
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
react-native: Not Found
```